# Expand $(e^{2x}-1-2x)/x^5$ into Laurent Series on 0<|x|<$\infty$ and classify its singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series, laurent-series

I guess I'm having difficulty with this because its not in the form of a polynomial expression, which is what I've been taught.  Nevertheless here's what I did:

I know that the expansion for $e^{2x}=\sum x^{2k}/2k!$.  I'm not entirely sure what to do next but I have to basically subtract 1 and 2x and divide by $x^5$.  Then I get this expression

$(\sum (2x)^{k}/k!-1-2x)/x^5$

However, I know that Laurent Series have to look something like:
$\sum a_n(x-c)^n$, with a sum that goes from negative to positive infinity.  I really don't know what to do and could really use some valuable guidance.

Comment: If $e^{x} = \sum \limits_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k}}{k!}$, then $e^{2x} = \dots$

Comment: I believe I changed it now to the right series.

Comment: You still have to correct the first instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your series for $e^{2x}$ should be
$$e^{2x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2x)^{k}}{k!}.$$
Note that this is equal to
$$e^{2x} = 1 + 2x + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(2x)^{k}}{k!},$$
so we have that
$$e^{2x} - 1 - 2x = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(2x)^{k}}{k!}.$$
Finally, by dividing by $x^{5}$, we get
$$\frac{e^{2x}-1-2x}{x^{5}} = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{2^{k}}{k!} x^{k-5} = \sum_{k=-3}^{\infty} \frac{2^{k+5}}{(k+5)!} x^{k}.$$
If you insist on putting it in the form $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} a_{k} (x-c)^{k}$, then we have $c = 0, a_{k} = 0$ for $k < -3$, and $a_{k} = \frac{2^{k+5}}{(k+5)!}$ for $k \geq -3$.

Comment: can you explain how you got the $a_k$?